# Установка RHQ на Windows 7 не завершается из-за исключения

Tags: java-ee, wildfly, rhel

Пробую установить RHQ Server последней версии на свою рабочую машину OS Win 7.
Прочитал уже кучу мануалов, правил вроде бы все, но результат тот же, ищет непонятную машину локально и по странному порту. В конфигах нигде не увидел ничего подобного, ну и собственно не ставится вообще. Подскажите, в какую сторону копать?

Вот журнал установки и сообщение об ошибке, выдаваемые установочным скриптом:

```
c:\rhq\bin>rhqctl.bat install --server
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=128M; support was removed in 8.0
13:36:39,207 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.3.0.Final-redhat-2
13:36:39,560 INFO  [org.rhq.server.control.command.Install] RHQ Storage is not installed locally. Installing RHQ Server using configured RHQ Storage cluster.
13:36:39,569 INFO  [org.rhq.server.control.command.Install] The RHQ Server must be started to complete its installation. Starting the RHQ server in preparation of running the serve
r installer...
The RHQ Server [rhqserver-SBTLED-AD105020] service is not installed - ╙ърчрээр  ёыєцср эх єёЄрэютыхэр. (0x424)
The RHQ Server [rhqserver-SBTLED-AD105020] service is not installed - ╙ърчрээр  ёыєцср эх єёЄрэютыхэр. (0x424)
Unable to install the RHQ Server [rhqserver-SBTLED-AD105020] service - ╚ь  єўхЄэющ чряшёш чрфрэю эхтхЁэю шыш эх ёє∙хёЄтєхЄ, шыш цх эхтхЁхэ єърчрээ√щ ярЁюы№. (0x421)
The RHQ Server [rhqserver-SBTLED-AD105020] service is not installed - ╙ърчрээр  ёыєцср эх єёЄрэютыхэр. (0x424)
13:36:41,620 INFO  [org.rhq.server.control.command.Install] Waiting for the RHQ Server to start in preparation of running the server installer...
13:36:47,068 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.3.0.Final-redhat-2
13:36:47,140 INFO  [org.rhq.enterprise.server.installer.InstallerServiceImpl] The server is preconfigured and ready for auto-install.
13:36:47,188 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.9.GA-redhat-1
13:36:47,193 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.9.GA-redhat-1
13:36:47,312 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version (unknown)
13:37:47,850 ERROR [org.rhq.enterprise.server.installer.Installer] The installer will now exit due to previous errors: java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out before being able to su
ccessfully connect to the server
        at org.rhq.enterprise.server.installer.InstallerServiceImpl.testModelControllerClient(InstallerServiceImpl.java:1255) [rhq-installer-util-4.13.1.jar:4.13.1]
        at org.rhq.enterprise.server.installer.InstallerServiceImpl.preInstall(InstallerServiceImpl.java:332) [rhq-installer-util-4.13.1.jar:4.13.1]
        at org.rhq.enterprise.server.installer.InstallerServiceImpl.test(InstallerServiceImpl.java:257) [rhq-installer-util-4.13.1.jar:4.13.1]
        at org.rhq.enterprise.server.installer.Installer.doInstall(Installer.java:96) [rhq-installer-util-4.13.1.jar:4.13.1]
        at org.rhq.enterprise.server.installer.Installer.main(Installer.java:59) [rhq-installer-util-4.13.1.jar:4.13.1]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:292) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:455) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Cannot obtain client connection to the RHQ app server!!
        at org.rhq.enterprise.server.installer.InstallerServiceImpl.testModelControllerClient(InstallerServiceImpl.java:1349) [rhq-installer-util-4.13.1.jar:4.13.1]
        at org.rhq.enterprise.server.installer.InstallerServiceImpl.testModelControllerClient(InstallerServiceImpl.java:1230) [rhq-installer-util-4.13.1.jar:4.13.1]
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012174: Could not connect to remote://127.0.0.1:9999. The connection failed
        at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeForResult(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:129) [jboss-as-controller-client-7.4.0.Final-redhat
-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.execute(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:81) [jboss-as-controller-client-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4
.0.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.rhq.common.jbossas.client.controller.JBossASClient.execute(JBossASClient.java:283) [rhq-jboss-as-dmr-client-4.13.1.jar:4.13.1]
        at org.rhq.common.jbossas.client.controller.CoreJBossASClient.getSystemProperties(CoreJBossASClient.java:103) [rhq-jboss-as-dmr-client-4.13.1.jar:4.13.1]
        at org.rhq.enterprise.server.installer.InstallerServiceImpl.testModelControllerClient(InstallerServiceImpl.java:1295) [rhq-installer-util-4.13.1.jar:4.13.1]
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012174: Could not connect to remote://127.0.0.1:9999. The connection failed
        at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionUtils.connectSync(ProtocolConnectionUtils.java:129) [jboss-as-protocol-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionManager$EstablishingConnection.connect(ProtocolConnectionManager.java:256) [jboss-as-protocol-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Fina
l-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionManager.connect(ProtocolConnectionManager.java:70) [jboss-as-protocol-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.FutureManagementChannel$Establishing.getChannel(FutureManagementChannel.java:204) [jboss-as-protocol-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redh
at-4]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.RemotingModelControllerClient.getOrCreateChannel(RemotingModelControllerClient.java:144) [jboss-as-controller-client-7.4.0.Final-redh
at-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.RemotingModelControllerClient$1.getChannel(RemotingModelControllerClient.java:65) [jboss-as-controller-client-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.ja
r:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.as.protocolJava HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=128M; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=128M; support was removed in 8.0
.mgmt.ManagementChannelHandler.executeRequest(ManagementChannelHandler.java:117) [jboss-as-protocol-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementChannelHandler.executeRequest(ManagementChannelHandler.java:92) [jboss-as-protocol-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeRequest(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:236) [jboss-as-controller-client-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4
.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.execute(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:141) [jboss-as-controller-client-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.
4.0.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeForResult(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:127) [jboss-as-controller-client-7.4.0.Final-redhat
-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
        ... 15 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
        at org.xnio.nio.NioXnioWorker$1.handleEvent(NioXnioWorker.java:329)
        at org.xnio.nio.NioXnioWorker$1.handleEvent(NioXnioWorker.java:325)
        at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:72)
        at org.xnio.nio.NioHandle.run(NioHandle.java:90)
        at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:198)
        at ...asynchronous invocation...(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.doConnect(EndpointImpl.java:270)
        at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.doConnect(EndpointImpl.java:251)
        at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.connect(EndpointImpl.java:349)
        at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.connect(EndpointImpl.java:337)
        at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionUtils.connect(ProtocolConnectionUtils.java:80) [jboss-as-protocol-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionUtils.connectSync(ProtocolConnectionUtils.java:99) [jboss-as-protocol-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
        ... 25 more

13:37:47,902 INFO  [org.rhq.server.control.command.Install] The RHQ Server is ready to be upgraded by the server installer.
13:37:47,904 INFO  [org.rhq.server.control.command.Install] Installing RHQ Server
13:37:47,908 INFO  [org.rhq.server.control.command.Install] The RHQ Server installer is running
13:37:47,960 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.9.GA-redhat-1
13:37:47,968 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.9.GA-redhat-1
13:37:48,045 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version (unknown)
13:37:48,392 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.3.0.Final-redhat-2
13:37:48,465 INFO  [org.rhq.enterprise.server.installer.InstallerServiceImpl] The server is preconfigured and ready for auto-install.
13:37:48,513 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.9.GA-redhat-1
13:37:48,518 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.9.GA-redhat-1
13:37:48,634 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version (unknown)
13:37:49,119 ERROR [org.rhq.server.control.command.Install] An error occurred while checking to see if the server is initialized: c:\rhq\logs\server.log (Не удается найти указанный
файл)
13:38:49,194 ERROR [org.rhq.enterprise.server.installer.Installer] The installer will now exit due to previous errors: java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out before being able to su
ccessfully connect to the server
        at org.rhq.enterprise.server.installer.InstallerServiceImpl.testModelControllerClient(InstallerServiceImpl.java:1255) [rhq-installer-util-4.13.1.jar:4.13.1]
        at org.rhq.enterprise.server.installer.InstallerServiceImpl.preInstall(InstallerServiceImpl.java:332) [rhq-installer-util-4.13.1.jar:4.13.1]
        at org.rhq.enterprise.server.installer.Installer.doInstall(Installer.java:134) [rhq-installer-util-4.13.1.jar:4.13.1]
        at org.rhq.enterprise.server.installer.Installer.main(Installer.java:59) [rhq-installer-util-4.13.1.jar:4.13.1]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:292) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:455) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Cannot obtain client connection toJava HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=128M; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=128M; support was removed in 8.0
the RHQ app server!!
        at org.rhq.enterprise.server.installer.InstallerServiceImpl.testModelControllerClient(InstallerServiceImpl.java:1349) [rhq-installer-util-4.13.1.jar:4.13.1]
        at org.rhq.enterprise.server.installer.InstallerServiceImpl.testModelControllerClient(InstallerServiceImpl.java:1230) [rhq-installer-util-4.13.1.jar:4.13.1]
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012174: Could not connect to remote://127.0.0.1:9999. The connection failed
        at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeForResult(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:129) [jboss-as-controller-client-7.4.0.Final-redhat
-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.execute(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:81) [jboss-as-controller-client-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4
.0.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.rhq.common.jbossas.client.controller.JBossASClient.execute(JBossASClient.java:283) [rhq-jboss-as-dmr-client-4.13.1.jar:4.13.1]
        at org.rhq.common.jbossas.client.controller.CoreJBossASClient.getSystemProperties(CoreJBossASClient.java:103) [rhq-jboss-as-dmr-client-4.13.1.jar:4.13.1]
        at org.rhq.enterprise.server.installer.InstallerServiceImpl.testModelControllerClient(InstallerServiceImpl.java:1295) [rhq-installer-util-4.13.1.jar:4.13.1]
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012174: Could not connect to remote://127.0.0.1:9999. The connection failed
        at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionUtils.connectSync(ProtocolConnectionUtils.java:129) [jboss-as-protocol-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionManager$EstablishingConnection.connect(ProtocolConnectionManager.java:256) [jboss-as-protocol-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Fina
l-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionManager.connect(ProtocolConnectionManager.java:70) [jboss-as-protocol-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.FutureManagementChannel$Establishing.getChannel(FutureManagementChannel.java:204) [jboss-as-protocol-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redh
at-4]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.RemotingModelControllerClient.getOrCreateChannel(RemotingModelControllerClient.java:144) [jboss-as-controller-client-7.4.0.Final-redh
at-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.RemotingModelControllerClient$1.getChannel(RemotingModelControllerClient.java:65) [jboss-as-controller-client-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.ja
r:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementChannelHandler.executeRequest(ManagementChannelHandler.java:117) [jboss-as-protocol-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementChannelHandler.executeRequest(ManagementChannelHandler.java:92) [jboss-as-protocol-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeRequest(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:236) [jboss-as-controller-client-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4
.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.execute(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:141) [jboss-as-controller-client-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.
4.0.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeForResult(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:127) [jboss-as-controller-client-7.4.0.Final-redhat
-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
        at org.xnio.nio.NioXnioWorker$1.handleEvent(NioXnioWorker.java:329)
        at org.xnio.nio.NioXnioWorker$1.handleEvent(NioXnioWorker.java:325)
        at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:72)
        at org.xnio.nio.NioHandle.run(NioHandle.java:90)
        at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:198)
        at ...asynchronous invocation...(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.doConnect(EndpointImpl.java:270)
        at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.doConnect(EndpointImpl.java:251)
        at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.connect(EndpointImpl.java:349)
        at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.connect(EndpointImpl.java:337)
        at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionUtils.connect(ProtocolConnectionUtils.java:80) [jboss-as-protocol-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
        at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionUtils.connectSync(ProtocolConnectionUtils.java:99) [jboss-as-protocol-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
        ... 24 more

The RHQ Server [rhqserver-SBTLED-AD105020] service is not installed - ╙ърчрээр  ёыєцср эх єёЄрэютыхэр. (0x424)
13:43:21,772 ERROR [org.rhq.server.control.RHQControl] c:\rhq\logs\server.log (Не удается найти указанный файл)
13:43:21,772 WARN  [org.rhq.server.control.command.Install] UNDO: Removing server-installed marker file and management user and reverting to original standalone-full.xml
13:43:21,773 WARN  [org.rhq.server.control.command.Install] UNDO: Stopping component: --server
The RHQ Server [rhqserver-SBTLED-AD105020] service is not installed - ╙ърчрээр  ёыєцср эх єёЄрэютыхэр. (0x424)
13:43:22,025 WARN  [org.rhq.server.control.command.Install] UNDO: Reverting server properties file
```